# Regex pattern infinite number of times except last one different

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to check if a text input is valid.
The pattern is [NumberBetween1And999]['x'][NumberBetween1And999][','][White space Optional] repeated infinite times.

I need this to make an order from a string: the first number is the product id and the second number is the quantity for the product.

Examples: of good texts:

```
1x1
2x1,3x1
1x3, 4x1
```

Should not catch:

```
1x1,
1,1, 1x1,
9999x1
1x1,99999x1
```

I'm blocked there: `^(([1-9][0-9]{0,2})x([1-9][0-9]{0,2}),)*$`

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}x[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,\s*[1-9][0-9]{0,2}x[1-9][0-9]{0,2})*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}x[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` Match a digit 1-9 and 2 optional digits 0-9, then `x` and again the digits part
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `,\s*` Match a comma and optional whitespace char
  - `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}x[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` Match the same pattern as at the beginning
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to also match a single part without a comma
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c2%7dx%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c2%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cs*%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c2%7dx%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c2%7d%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=1x1%0d%0a2x1%2c3x1%0d%0a1x3%2c+4x1%0d%0a%0d%0a1x1%2c%0d%0a1%2c1%2c+1x1%2c%0d%0a9999x1%0d%0a1x1%2c99999x1&o=m)